# Animating a moving dot

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I need to animate a dot/plot that moves randomly until it crosses a circle, which it then stays on. Ideally, there would be several dots which, when eventually on the circle, would be equally distributed on said circle.
I've seen codes using matplotlib and matplotlib.animate which animated a function's graph, but I was not able to fully understand them.

Thanks for your time!

Edit:
[This is what it would look like with one dot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cggj3.png)

[And with several dots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZXyT.png)

Comment: It might be helpful, if you can state, what you already tried and/or what exactly it is, you do not understand. It should be easier to provide help then. :)

Comment: Well, for instance, there is this tutorial here:
https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2012/08/18/matplotlib-animation-tutorial/

When the author animates a number of points (third animation), where exactly is the part that generates not just one, but say 100 points?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've never animated anything in Python, so I though that I can learn something new, and wrote following code that animates a dot, so it moves in random directions. Maybe it will help You to start with Your task. The code is based on [matplotlib-animation-tutorial](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2012/08/18/matplotlib-animation-tutorial/).

EDIT: I had some long train trip and I've implemented the things You were asking for. You have a bunch of randomly moving dots here. Once they get inside the blue circle, they try to maximize the distance between them so after a while it looks like You wanted.

```
"""
Matplotlib Animation Example

author: Jake Vanderplas
email: vanderplas@astro.washington.edu
website: http://jakevdp.github.com
license: BSD
Please feel free to use and modify this, but keep the above information. Thanks!
"""
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
import math

# Initializing number of dots
N = 25


# Creating dot class
class dot(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 10 * np.random.random_sample()
        self.y = 10 * np.random.random_sample()
        self.velx = self.generate_new_vel()
        self.vely = self.generate_new_vel()

    def generate_new_vel(self):
        return (np.random.random_sample() - 0.5) / 5

    def move(self):
        def distance(x1, y1, x2, y2):
            return math.sqrt((x2 - x1) ** 2 + (y2 - y1) ** 2)

        def inside(x1, y1):
            if distance(x1, y1, 5, 5) <= 1:
                return True
            else:
                return False

        def calc_dist(d):
            ret = 0
            for x in dots:
                if inside(x.x, x.y) and x != d:                            
                    ret = ret + distance(x.x, x.y, d.x, d.y)
            return ret

        # if dot is inside the circle it tries to maximize the distances to
        # other dots inside circle
        if inside(self.x, self.y):
            dist = calc_dist(self)
            for i in xrange(1, 10):
                self.velx = self.generate_new_vel()
                self.vely = self.generate_new_vel()
                self.x = self.x + self.velx
                self.y = self.y + self.vely
                if calc_dist(self) <= dist or not inside(self.x, self.y):
                    self.x = self.x - self.velx
                    self.y = self.y - self.vely
        else:
            if np.random.random_sample() < 0.95:
                self.x = self.x + self.velx
                self.y = self.y + self.vely
            else:
                self.velx = self.generate_new_vel()
                self.vely = self.generate_new_vel()
                self.x = self.x + self.velx
                self.y = self.y + self.vely
            if self.x >= 10:
                self.x = 10
                self.velx = -1 * self.velx
            if self.x <= 0:
                self.x = 0
                self.velx = -1 * self.velx
            if self.y >= 10:
                self.y = 10
                self.vely = -1 * self.vely
            if self.y <= 0:
                self.y = 0
                self.vely = -1 * self.vely

# Initializing dots
dots = [dot() for i in xrange(N)]

# First set up the figure, the axis, and the plot element we want to animate
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 10), ylim=(0, 10))
d, = ax.plot([dot.x for dot in dots],
             [dot.y for dot in dots], 'ro')
circle = plt.Circle((5, 5), 1, color='b', fill=False)
ax.add_artist(circle)


# animation function.  This is called sequentially
def animate(i):
    for dot in dots:
        dot.move()
    d.set_data([dot.x for dot in dots],
               [dot.y for dot in dots])
    return d,

# call the animator.  blit=True means only re-draw the parts that have changed.
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=200, interval=20)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Few questions remain; would you be able to further explain this:
dot.get_xdata()[0] + random.uniform(-0.05, 0.05)
and also why there is a comma after the "dot"?

Also, how do I step up from this to several moving dots?

Comment: `random.uniform(-0.05, 0.05)` returns random number between `-0.05` and `0.05`, then it's added to `x` parameter of the dot; `dot,` is a tuple `(dot,)`; I think You can add more dots by adding parameters `x, y` to the lists `ax.plot([5], [5], 'ro')` but I'm not sure yet, maybe I will work some more on this code later.

Comment: @user5987384 I've edited the answer. Now You have multiple moving dots and they will stay inside blue circle like You wanted.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! Your code does exactly what I was looking for! Though there are a lot of things I don't understand (for example the classes and the self.), I'll do my best to try grasp a good understanding of it by doing some research.

Comment: This code helped me begin to understand object oriented programming in Python. The one thing that remains unclear is the function calc_dist : why are you using the command list(dots) and the variable ret?
In another program I'm writing, I need to get information on dots placed around a certain dot, that's why it would help me greatly.

Comment: I wanted the `calc_dist(d)` function to calculate the sum of distances from dot `d` to every other dot in the circle. I was accumulating that sum in variable `ret`. `list(dots)` simply creates copy of the list of all dots, so I can remove `d` from it and use it later. This function is not written very well, so maybe don't take it as an example.

Comment: I see; when testing the code, I tried to use the deepcopy function, which is supposed to create a list's copy as well, but the program subsequently stopped working. You don't happen to know why that could be?

Comment: Well, I'm not completely sure because I don't know what is in your code. But with `copy.deepcopy` that function would have to be written differently, for example You cant execute this line `pomdots.remove(d)` because there is no `d` object in the deepcopy. There is a new object with the same values as `d`. The truth is that You don't need to create any copy at all in order to make this function work and it's probably more efficient... I have edited the code.

Comment: Ok, I have solved that problem. Now, I have moving dots inside a box, and it's easy to tell them to "bounce back" once they are at the border, meaning multiply their velovity by -1. How can I have the same thing, but for a circle, so that the dots stay inside the circle? Thank you very much.

Comment: @user5987384 You can just proceed with the same principle. Detect the dots that are inside the circle (distance between them and the middle of the circle is less then a radius), and when they are trying to get out multiply their velocity by `-1`.

Comment: Problem is, if I simply multiply the velocity by -1, there isn't a "bouncing" effect, unless the angle at which the dot hits the circle is close to 90°.